team city package installer is downgrading package references
we have the following package references in the project

prism version 4.1.0
prism.core version 8.1.97
prism.wpf version 8.1.97

we build the project local using VS 2022, we are successful and we can execute the binary.
we have setup a team city build which pulls same project with the same references from a source repository.
the nuget installer does not install the versions specified either in the *.csproj file or package.config and downgrades the reference to the following:

prism version 4.0.0
prism.core version 6.0.0
prism.wpf version 6.0.0

the build of course fails and I have a step that clears all local nuget caches on failure.
I have checked our nuget feed and the packages specified in the package references are in the feed.
we have also removed all assembly binding maps from the app.config file.
I have provided two pictures one is what team city is fetching and the other is the package config where the version it is fetching is not allowed


